# How do I remove a duplicate dict in list, ignoring a dict key?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a list of dictionaries. Each dictionary has several key-values, and a single arbitrary (but important) key-value pair. For example

```
thelist = [
    {"key" : "value1", "k2" : "va1", "ignore_key" : "arb1"}, 
    {"key" : "value2", "k2" : "va2", "ignore_key" : "arb11"},
    {"key" : "value2", "k2" : "va2", "ignore_key" : "arb113"}
]
```

I would like to remove the duplicate dictionaries such that only the non- "ignore-key" values are ignored. I have seen a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python) on so - but it only considers entirely identical dicts. Is there a way to remove the almost duplicate such that the data above becomes

```
thelist = [
    {"key" : "value1", "k2" : "va1", "ignore_key" : "arb1"}, 
    {"key" : "value2", "k2" : "va2", "ignore_key" : "arb11"}
]
```

It doesn't matter which of the duplicates is ignored. How can I do this?

Comment: Are your values always hashable?

Comment: Thank you for your responses. Sorry - the example situation wasn't clear. There are multiple key-value pairs and only one key to ignore.

Comment: @DSM Yes, the values are always hashable (text and datetime objects).

Comment: @user4467853, I presumed they are grouped or how do you decide which to keep?

Comment: Somewhat overkill but you could do no_ignore = a_dict.copy(), del no_ignore ["ignore_key"].  Then apply Ami's add as you filter recipe to add a_dict while filtering on no_ignore.

Comment: Also are there the same keys in each dict and can different keys have the same values?

Answer (score 5):

Keep a set of the seen values for `key` and remove any dict that has the the same value:

```
st = set()

for d in thelist[:]:
    vals = d["key"],d["k2"]
    if vals in st:
        thelist.remove(d)
    st.add(vals)
print(thelist)

[{'k2': 'va1', 'ignore_key': 'arb1', 'key': 'value1'},
{'k2': 'va2', 'ignore_key': 'arb11', 'key': 'value2'}]
```

If the values are always grouped, you can use the `value` from `key` to group and get the first dict from each group:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
thelist[:] = [next(v) for _, v in groupby(thelist,itemgetter("key","k2"))]
print(thelist)]

print(thelist)
[{'key': 'value1', 'k2': 'va1', 'ignore_key': 'arb1'}, 
{'key': 'value2', 'k2': 'va2', 'ignore_key': 'arb11'}]
```

Or using a generator similar to DSM's answer to modify the original list without copying:

```
def filt(l):
    st = set()
    for d in l:
        vals = d["key"],d["k2"]
        if vals not in st:
            yield d
        st.add(vals)


thelist[:] = filt(thelist)

print(thelist)

 [{'k2': 'va1', 'ignore_key': 'arb1', 'key': 'value1'}, 
{'k2': 'va2', 'ignore_key': 'arb11', 'key': 'value2'}]
```

If you don't care which dupe is removes just use reversed:

```
st = set()

for d in reversed(thelist):
    vals = d["key"],d["k2"]
    if vals in st:
        thelist.remove(d)
    st.add(vals)
print(thelist)
```

To ignore all bar the ignore_key using groupby:

```
from itertools import groupby

thelist[:] = [next(v) for _, v in groupby(thelist, lambda d: 
                [val for k, val in d.items() if k != "ignore_key"])]
print(thelist)
[{'key': 'value1', 'k2': 'va1', 'ignore_key': 'arb1'},
 {'key': 'value2', 'k2': 'va2', 'ignore_key': 'arb11'}]
```

Answer (score 3):

You could cram things into a line or two, but I think it's cleaner just to write a function:

```
def f(seq, ignore_keys):
    seen = set()
    for elem in seq:
        index = frozenset((k,v) for k,v in elem.items() if k not in ignore_keys)
        if index not in seen:
            yield elem
            seen.add(index)
```

which gives

```
>>> list(f(thelist, ["ignore_key"]))
[{'ignore_key': 'arb1', 'k2': 'va1', 'key': 'value1'}, 
 {'ignore_key': 'arb11', 'k2': 'va2', 'key': 'value2'}]
```

This assumes your values are hashable.  (If they're not, the same code will work with `seen = []` and `seen.append(index)`, although it'll have bad performance for long lists.)

Answer (score 1):

Starting off with your original list:

```
thelist = [
    {"key" : "value1", "ignore_key" : "arb1"}, 
    {"key" : "value2", "ignore_key" : "arb11"},
    {"key" : "value2", "ignore_key" : "arb113"}
]
```

Create a set, and populate it while filtering the list.

```
uniques, theNewList = set(), []
for d in theList:]
    cur = d["key"] # Avoid multiple lookups of the same thing
    if cur not in uniques:
        theNewList.append(d)
    uniques.add(cur)
```

Finally, rename the list:

```
theList = theNewList
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a list of dicts you could use a dict of dicts. The key value on each one of your dict would be the key on the main dict.

Like this:

```
thedict = {}

thedict["value1"] = {"ignore_key" : "arb1", ...}  
thedict["value2"] = {"ignore_key" : "arb11", ...}
```

Since the dict wouldn't allow duplicate keys your problem wouldn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Without changing `thelist`

```
result = []
seen = set()
thelist = [
    {"key" : "value1", "ignore_key" : "arb1"},
    {"key" : "value2", "ignore_key" : "arb11"},
    {"key" : "value2", "ignore_key" : "arb113"}
]

for item in thelist:
    if item['key'] not in seen:
        result.append(item)
        seen.add(item['key'])

print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a set of the unique values and check against (& update) that:

```
values = {d['key'] for d in thelist}
newlist = []

for d in thelist:
    if d['key'] in values:
        newlist.append(d)
        values -= {d['key']}

thelist = newlist
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9427216/355230) to the linked question by using a dictionary instead of a set to remove duplicates.

The following first builds a temporary dictionary whose keys are a tuple of the items in each dictionary in `thelist` *except for ignored one* which is saved as the value associated with each of these keys. Doing so eliminates duplicates since they will become the same key, yet preserves the ignored key and its ignored value (of the last or only one seen).

The second step recreates `thelist` by creating dictionaries composed of a combination of each key plus its associated value from the items in the temporary dictionary.

You could combine these two steps into a completely unreadable one-liner if you wished...

```
thelist = [
    {"key" : "value1", "k2" : "va1", "ignore_key" : "arb1"},
    {"key" : "value2", "k2" : "va2", "ignore_key" : "arb11"},
    {"key" : "value2", "k2" : "va2", "ignore_key" : "arb113"}
]

IGNORED = "ignore_key"
temp = dict((tuple(item for item in d.items() if item[0] != IGNORED),
             (IGNORED, d.get(IGNORED))) for d in thelist)
thelist = [dict(key + (value,)) for key, value in temp.iteritems()]

for item in thelist:
    print item
```

Output:

```
{'ignore_key': 'arb1', 'k2': 'va1', 'key': 'value1'}
{'ignore_key': 'arb113', 'k2': 'va2', 'key': 'value2'}
```