# Python - Check for list duplicates

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python like this

```
my_list = [{'1':'A','2':'B'}]
```

And now I want to append some more `JSON` to `my_list` but first I want to check if the `JSON` I am adding already exists, how could I go about this?

So if I was going to append `{'2':'B','1':'A'}`, I would that not to be added?

How could I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Do you care about the order?

Comment: Is that a typo?  In the second `dict` you have `'A'` as a key

Comment: @SomethingSomething yes, order does not matter, I switched the order but I still do not want it to be added

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python TL;DR: use sets

Comment: I wanted to suggest using `set()` but it turns out that it is not hashable. It's probably going to be a more complex solution

Comment: yes, you don't just cast it to set, but the answer to the question I've linked to offers an one-liner solution for it.

Comment: I have another question - do your dictionaries always contain the same keys '1' and '2' ? If yes - we might be able to create some dummy class with '1' and '2' as fields and then it will be hashable and we'll be able to check in O(1) whether an object already exists in the list

Answer (score 2):

You can check if two dictionaries are identical with `==`

```
In [2]: {'1':'A','2':'B'}=={'2':'B','1':'A'}
Out[2]: True
```

Therefore to check if `JSON` exists in `my_list` you can simply do

```
if JSON in my_list:
    #blahblah
```

*Update:*

To use `set` with your data, you can define your own subclass and implement `__hash__()` method. You can start from here:

```
class MyJSON(dict):
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(json.dumps(self,sort_keys=True))
```

Example:

```
a=MyJSON({'1':'A','2':'B'})
b=MyJSON({'1':'A','2':'C'})
c=MyJSON({'2':'B','1':'A'}) ## should be equal to a
print a==c # should be True
my_set=set()
my_set.add(a)
my_set.add(b)
my_set.add(c)
for item in my_set:
    print item,
## output is {'1': 'A', '2': 'C'} {'1': 'A', '2': 'B'}
```

Comment: yes but as the array get longer this doesn't work, unless i add a loop to go through each one, which I am trying to avoid

Comment: @spenf10 but `in` are supposed to act similarly to looping for lists? Have you checked that the new `JSON` you are appending is 100% identical to an old one? Anyway if you are having a long list and need to check everytime maybe you should consider `set` as some answers above.

Comment: right but a `set` doesn't allow me to add a dictionary to it

Comment: @spenf10 Yeah... Sorry I have just realised that. How about doing `json.dumps(JSON, sort_keys=True)` to convert your data to string then? I know it will cost a lot but in some cases this might be the best way to do.

Comment: @spenf10 I found a way to support `set`, see my update

Comment: This solution looks very nice to me

Answer (score 0):

The canonical data structure to use for avoiding duplicates is the `set`. As you've mentioned, you can't do this because you'll be adding `dict`s to the set, which are unhashable.

The usual fix for this is either to define a custom `dict`-like object that *is* hashable, or to freeze your dict into something hashable and add *that* to the set. We'll do the latter.

```
my_list = [{1:2, 3:4}, {3:4, 1:2}]
result = set()

for json_data in my_list:
    result.add(frozenset(json_data.items()))

print(result)
# {frozenset({(1, 2), (3, 4)})}
```