# Filtering python list of duplicated

Tags: python

I'm new to python, and I'm having the following problem to solve.

I have a list of dictionaries, with duplicated `name` values eg: `reel1`.

I need to append to a new list the dictionaries that has unique names, for that I'm using the greatest `version` number, un this case that would be `reel1` version `10`

```
store = [  
  {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel1_c09', 'range': '12-120', 'version': '09', 'name': 'reel1'},
  {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel1_c09', 'range': '12-120', 'version': '10', 'name': 'reel1'},
  {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel2_c09', 'range': None, 'version': '09', 'name': 'reel2'} 
]
```

The result should be like this.

```
result = [
    {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel1_c09', 'range': '12-120', 'version': '10', 'name': 'reel1'},
    {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel2_c09', 'range': None, 'version': '09', 'name': 'reel2'} 
]
```

Many thanks for you're help.

Comment: there's a thing called [`set`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set). Learn about it. I'm sure that's what you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will do:

```
store = [
  {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel1_c09', 'range': '12-120', 'version': '09', 'name': 'reel1'},
  {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel1_c09', 'range': '12-120', 'version': '10', 'name': 'reel1'},
  {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel2_c09', 'range': None, 'version': '09', 'name': 'reel2'}
]

l = [reduce(lambda x, y: x if int(x['version']) > int(y['version']) else y, filter(lambda e: e['url'] == n, store)) for n in {d['url'] for d in store}]
print l

[{'url': 'n0:project:film:reel2_c09', 'range': None, 'version': '09', 'name': 'reel2'}, {'url': 'n0:project:film:reel1_c09', 'range': '12-120', 'version': '10', 'name': 'reel1'}]
```

Explaining the code:
Set the `url` and for each one of them filter the store list taking the duplicates and takes the biggest version one reducing that sublist.
Expanding by parts:

Take unique url values in the store list:

```
{d['url'] for d in store}
```

Collecting all duplicades and listing them together:

```
filter(lambda e: e['url'] == n, store))
```

Reducing each sublist with duplicates and taking the one with higher version:

```
reduce(lambda x, y: x if int(x['version']) > int(y['version']) else y
```

Comment: I'm having a syntax error in the for loop `{d['url'] for d in store}` I don't see why. I'm using python 2.6.2

Comment: @FilmmoreBrussels use `set([d['url'] for d in store])` instead and check