# Remove duplicates from a list of dicts in Python updating key:value for duplicate counter

Tags: python, list, dictionary, duplicates

I have a list called `dict_list` containing a number of dictionaries with possible duplicates. My goal is not only to [remove duplicates from a list of dicts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python) but also to *keep their count for each of remaining dictionaries*, stored as a key:value (`dupe_count:int`) pair.

Comment: can you provide us the code you have tried?

Comment: @Mani currently I remove duplicates using `set()` as in solution I've attached a link to, but I have no idea how to modify key:value for unique dictionaries on the go.

Comment: The question you've linked removes duplicate dictionaries from a list, so that the input `[{'a': 123, 'b': 1234}, {'a': 3222, 'b': 1234}, {'a': 123, 'b': 1234}]` gives output `[{'a': 3222, 'b': 1234}, {'a': 123, 'b': 1234}]`.  Can you explain how you want to change this?  Are you looking to produce `Counter({(('a', 123), ('b', 1234)): 2, (('a', 3222), ('b', 1234)): 1})`, or `[{'a': 246, 'b': 2648}, {'a': 3222, 'b': 1234}]`?  Please give sample input and expected output.