# Sorting a list of dictionaries by all keys being unique

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

Pulling my hair out with this one.

I have a list of dictionaries without a unique primary ID key for each unique entry (the dictionary is built on the fly):

```
dicts = [{'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe', 'code': 'crumpets'},
         {'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'roe', 'code': 'roe'},
         {'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe', 'code': 'crumpets'},
         {'firstname': 'thom', 'lastname': 'doe', 'code': 'crumpets'},
]
```

How do I go about filtering out lists of dictionaries like this where any repeating {} within the list are removed? So I need to check if all three of the dictionary keys match up with another in the list...and then discard that from the `dict` if that check is met.

So, for my example above, the first and third "entries" need to be removed as they are duplicates.

Comment: So from the moment there are duplicates, you want to remove *all* elements?

Comment: Could you display what you are waiting for?

Comment: map the dicts to tuple pairs, create a set of those (which makes them unique) and map them back to dicts

Comment: No - just remove the duplicates. So if one dictionary in a list is equal to another - drop one of these (but not both).

Comment: possible solution , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use create frozensets from the dicts and put those in a set to remove dupes:

```
dcts = [dict(d) for d in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in dcts)]
print(dcts)
```

---

```
[{'code': 'roe', 'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'roe'},
 {'code': 'crumpets', 'firstname': 'thom', 'lastname': 'doe'},
 {'code': 'crumpets', 'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe'}]
```

If you choose to remove all entries of the duplicates you can use a counter:

```
from collections import Counter

dcts = [dict(d) for d, cnt in Counter(frozenset(d.items()) for d in dcts).items() 
                                                                      if cnt==1]
print(dcts)
```

---

```
[{'code': 'roe', 'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'roe'},
 {'code': 'crumpets', 'firstname': 'thom', 'lastname': 'doe'}]
```

Comment: Will see if I can implement this - but not sure I understand how you can define a dictionary on the fly and then cross check it. Will need to implement this and do some more reading I think. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any reason other than onelining this, to not use simple for loop with new container like this: `new_ct = []` and `for item in ct: if item not in new_ct: new_ct.append(item)` ?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts First part of his answer does what you want `dcts = [dict(d) for d in set(frozenset(d.items()) for d in dcts)]`

Comment: @SardorbekImomaliev Apologies, yes that is correct. I was in the middle of editing my comment when I realised.

Comment: To expand upon my above comment, surely dcts is referenced before an assignment?

Comment: @MichaelRoberts `dcts` is your list of dicts it is called `dicts` in your question

Comment: I see. Yes this works - I should probably have given a different variable name for my dict. Accepted answer - very elegantly done in one line.

Answer (score 2):

Remove duplicates in a list of non-hashable elements requires you to make them hashable on the fly:

```
def remove_duplicated_dicts(elements):
    seen = set()
    result = []
    for element in elements:
        element_as_tuple = tuple(element.items())
        if element_as_tuple not in seen:
            seen.add(element_as_tuple)
            result.append(element)
    return result

d = [{'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe', 'code': "crumpets"},
        {'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'roe', 'code': "roe"},
        {'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe', 'code': "crumpets"},
        {'firstname': 'thom', 'lastname': 'doe', 'code': "crumpets"},
]

print(remove_duplicated_dicts(d))
```

**PS.**

Non-obvious differences with the accepted answer of Moses Koledoye (as of 2017-06-19 at 13:00:00):

- preservation of the original list order;
- faster conversions: `dict -> tuple` instead of `dict -> frozendict -> dict` (take it with a grain of salt: I have made no benchmark).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer - although I am very grateful for your answer I have accepted a higher voted answer (I was also working within a function with Django so I didn't want to nest a base dictionary sorting method above Django based methods). But thank you, nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Given the **values of the dictionary are hashable**, we can generate our own *uniqness* filter:

```
def uniq(iterable, key = lambda x:x):
    keys = set()
    for item in iterable:
        ky = key(item)
        if ky not in keys:
            yield item
            keys.add(ky)
```

We can then simply use the filter, like:

```
list(uniq(dicts,key=lambda x:(x['firstname'],x['lastname'],x['code'])))
```

The filter maintains the original order, and will - for this example - generate:

```
>>> list(uniq(dicts,key=lambda x:(x['firstname'],x['lastname'],x['code'])))
[{'code': 'crumpets', 'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'doe'},
 {'code': 'roe', 'firstname': 'john', 'lastname': 'roe'},
 {'code': 'crumpets', 'firstname': 'thom', 'lastname': 'doe'}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer - although I am very grateful for your answer I have accepted a higher voted answer (I was also working within a function with Django so I didn't want to nest a base dictionary sorting method above Django based methods). But thank you, nonetheless.