# finding duplicates in a list of dictionaries

Tags: python

I have a python list of dictionaries which could be something like:

```
l = [{'id': 'scissor'}, {'id': 'cloth'}, {'id': 'scissor'}]
```

Now, I was wondering if there is an efficient way to remove duplicates from this list. So the result should be something like:

```
r = [{'id': 'scissor'}, {'id': 'cloth'}]
```

I tried using `frozenset` but the dictionary type cannot be hashed. Is there an efficient way to do this from any structures in the python library?

**EDIT**
The items are considered duplicate if the dict are completely the same.

Comment: Under which requirement do you want to remove the dicts? If they have the same keys? or onyl if they are completely the same?

Comment: @Bernhard: If they are completely the same as in the example.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Comment: Can we create a `hashset` of all the elements of `l` with any value. The keys/elements of that `hashset` will give us `r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have to be efficient:

```
from functools import partial
import json

list(map(json.loads, set(map(partial(json.dumps, sort_keys=True), l))))
```

If you do have to be efficient:

```
serialized = map(tuple, map(sorted, map(dict.items, l)))
unique = set(serialized)
result = list(map(dict, unique))
```

Answer (score 4):

```
r = [x for i,x in enumerate(l) if x not in l[:i]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Should work:

```
l2 = []

for d in l:
    if d not in l2:
        l2.append(d)
```

Comment: not fancy but dead simple

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you the following simplest way:

```
l = [{'id': 'scissor'}, {'id': 'cloth'}, {'id': 'scissor'}]

r= []
for i in l:
    if i not in r:
        r.append(i)

print(r)   # [{'id': 'scissor'}, {'id': 'cloth'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Set items have to be hashable, which dicts are not. You can use `pickle` to serialize all the dicts, then use `set` to obtain unique items, and finally deserialize them back to dicts:

```
import pickle
print(list(map(pickle.loads, set(map(pickle.dumps, l)))))
```

This outputs:

```
[{'id': 'cloth'}, {'id': 'scissor'}]
```