# How to delete duplicated dictionary objects from a List of dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I want to delete duplicated dictionary objects from  a List of dictionaries.
I don't want the dict element that has the same 'plate' element with another dict element in the list. I want it only once.

```
datalist = [

{
    'plate': "01",
    'confidence' : "80"
},

{
    'plate': "01",
    'confidence' : "60"
},

{
    'plate': "02",
    'confidence' : "91"
},

{
    'plate': "02",
    'confidence' : "91"
},
]
```

My output should be like this:

```
datalist = [

{
    'plate': "01",
    'confidence' : "80"
},

{
    'plate': "02",
    'confidence' : "91"
},
]
```

This is my code, but I'm not getting the exact result.

```
def filter(datalist):
    previous = ""
    for data in datalist:
        current  = data['plate']
        if current is previous:
            datalist.remove(data)
        previous = current 

    return datalist

datalist = [

    {
        'plate': "01",
        'confidence' : "80"
    },

    {
        'plate': "01",
        'confidence' : "60"
    },

    {
        'plate': "02",
        'confidence' : "91"
    },

    {
        'plate': "02",
        'confidence' : "91"
    },
]


print (filter(datalist))
```

This gives me the output:

```
[

    {
        'plate': "01",
        'confidence' : "80"
    },

    {
        'plate': "02",
        'confidence' : "91"
    },

    {
        'plate': "02",
        'confidence' : "91"
    },
]
```

which is not expected, what's wrong with my code.

Comment: Related, not exact duplicate as here we only want to consider one key when considering duplicates: [Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)

Comment: you can also use pandas

import pandas as pd;
df = pd.DataFrame(data = datalist);
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['plate'],keep='first',inplace=True);
output = df.to_dict(orient='record')

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If any element from the groups of duplicates is acceptable, you could do:

```
datalist = [
    {'plate': "01", 'confidence': "80"},
    {'plate': "01", 'confidence': "60"},
    {'plate': "02", 'confidence': "91"},
    {'plate': "02", 'confidence': "91"},
]

result = list({ d['plate'] : d for d in datalist }.values())
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'plate': '02', 'confidence': '91'}, {'plate': '01', 'confidence': '60'}]
```

The idea is to create a dictionary where the keys are values of `plate` and the values are the dictionaries themselves. If you want to keep the first duplicate entries use [reversed](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```
result = list({d['plate']: d for d in reversed(datalist)}.values())
```

**Output**

```
[{'plate': '02', 'confidence': '91'}, {'plate': '01', 'confidence': '80'}]
```

Comment: This produces the wrong result because the last duplicated entries are kept, not the first.

Comment: @timgeb OP didn't clearly specify that they want the first entry - only that they don't want duplicate entries.

Comment: @MatthiasFischer OP specified the desired output.

Comment: you can still do this by replacing `datalist` with `datalist[::-1]` or `reversed(datalist)` for something more loop-efficient.

Comment: @timgeb For the first example, but we don't know if they always want the first entry. You're probably right and I'm being pedantic, but it's not explicitly stated. :)

Comment: @timgeb Updated the answer!

Comment: @DanielMesejo Thank you so much for the quick response. It works the way I wanted. The only piece of puzzle left was to preserve the order, and for that I added another line of code, `results_sorted = sorted(results, key=lambda k: k['epoch_time'])` Fortunately I got the "Epoch Time" in the list , which and others few keys I removed for the clarity of the question. And I sorted the dictionaries with "epoch time" and it is fine now.

Answer (score 4):

you can also use pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(data = datalist)
df.drop_duplicates(subset = ['plate'],keep='first',inplace=True)
output = df.to_dict(orient='record')
```

keep = 'first' or 'last' will help in which entry to keep in output

Comment: Huh, I did not know that you could pass `'record'` instead of `'records'`. This seems to be undocumented. +1 for obscure knowledge :)

Comment: Update: seems like you can pass `'r'`, `'re'`, ..., `'records'`, `'recordsasdf'`, ...

Comment: :D Thanks @timgeb . We can use anything that starts with 'r' . I have just checked the source code. 
http://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/v0.23.4/pandas/core/frame.py#L987-L1102

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to only keep the first duplicated dict found, You can use `setdefault()`:

```
datalist = [
    {"plate": "01", "confidence": "80"},
    {"plate": "01", "confidence": "60"},
    {"plate": "02", "confidence": "91"},
    {"plate": "02", "confidence": "91"},
]

result = {}
for d in datalist:
    result.setdefault(d["plate"], d)

print(list(result.values()))
# [{'plate': '01', 'confidence': '80'}, {'plate': '02', 'confidence': '91'}]
```

If you instead want the last duplicates, simply iterate in [`reverse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`unique_everseen` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), also available in 3rd party [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
from operator import itemgetter    

datalist = list(unique_everseen(datalist, key=itemgetter('plate')))
```

Internally, this solution uses `set` to keep track of seen plates, yielding only dictionaries with new plate values. Therefore, ordering is maintained and only the first instance of any given plate is kept.

Comment: Nice use of `itemgetter()` here.

Comment: Good answer for the uninitiated, like me. Although, I prefer pandas as more simple method.

Answer (score 3):

If you are a `pandas` user, you can consider

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> datalist = [{'plate': "01", 'confidence': "80"}, {'plate': "01", 'confidence': "60"}, {'plate': "02", 'confidence': "91"}, {'plate': "02", 'confidence': "91"}]
>>> pd.DataFrame(datalist).drop_duplicates('plate').to_dict(orient='records')                                                                               
[{'confidence': '80', 'plate': '01'}, {'confidence': '91', 'plate': '02'}]
```

If you want to keep the last seen duplicates, pass `keep='last'`.

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(datalist).drop_duplicates('plate', keep='last').to_dict(orient='records')
[{'confidence': '60', 'plate': '01'}, {'confidence': '91', 'plate': '02'}]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one groupby:

```
list(map(lambda x: next(x[1]), groupby(sorted(datalist, key=lambda d: d['plate']), lambda d: d['plate'])))
```

Results:

```
[{'plate': '01', 'confidence': '80'}, {'plate': '02', 'confidence': '91'}]
```

Comment: this requires the initial list to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

Good old verbose `for` loop, then list comprehension:

```
tmp=[]
for dct in datalist:
  if not any(e[0] == dct["plate"] for e in tmp):
    tmp.append((dct["plate"], dct["confidence"]))


[ {"plate": plate, "confidence": confidence} for plate, confidence in tmp ]
#=> [{'plate': '01', 'confidence': '80'}, {'plate': '02', 'confidence': '91'}]
```