# How to remove duplicates from list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries in python as follows:

```
[{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
 {'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.1.2'},
 {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]
```

(parsing some data txt file)

What I wanna do:

If category and name are the same I wanna leave the first appearance of a package entry and remove the rest, so the final output would look like:

```
[{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
{'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]
```

How should I achieve this? I tried converting the list of dictionaries to a dictionary and then iterate over it with `dict.items()` but with no luck.

Comment: Please take a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Comment: @Dharmesh These aren't really duplicates, though. Only 2 key/value pairs are the same; the `version` is different.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `itertools.groupby`, and take first of each group:

```
def uniq(lst):
    for _, grp in itertools.groupby(lst, lambda d: (d['category'], d['name'])):
        yield list(grp)[0]
lst = [{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
       {'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.1.2'},
       {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]
print(list(uniq(lst))
```

Comment: This only works if the input list is already sorted by category and name, though. If you move `hexchat` inbetween the two `irssi`, this won't work.

Comment: right. assumed it sorted, as in the example above. Otherwise you just need to sort it before pass into function.

Comment: You don't have to consume all the group by creating a list. You can just `yield next(grp)`.

Answer (score 8):

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) to keep track of all `(category, name)` pairs you've already seen:

```
lst = [
    {'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
    {'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.1.2'},
    {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}
]

seen = set()
result = []

for dic in lst:
    key = (dic['category'], dic['name'])
    if key in seen:
        continue

    result.append(dic)
    seen.add(key)

print(result)
# output: [{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
#          {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]
```

This can be generalized into a function:

```
def keep_first(iterable, key=None):
    if key is None:
        key = lambda x: x

    seen = set()
    for elem in iterable:
        k = key(elem)
        if k in seen:
            continue

        yield elem
        seen.add(k)
```

```
>>> list(keep_first(lst, lambda d: (d['category'], d['name'])))
[{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
 {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the last version, you could create a dictionary that holds the software info for the last version of each category/name pair.  Then get the list of values from that dictionary of dictionaries:

```
software = [{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
            {'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.1.2'},
            {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]

lastVersion = dict()
for softInfo in software:
    key = (softInfo['category'],softInfo['name'])
    if key not in lastVersion or lastVersion[key]['version'] < softInfo['version']:
        lastVersion[key] = softInfo
software = list(lastVersion.values())

print(software)

# [{'category': 'software', 'name': 'irssi', 'version': '1.2.0'},
#  {'category': 'software', 'name': 'hexchat', 'version': '2.14.2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to convert the list of dicts to a list of tuples. Then use `set()` to eliminate duplicates and thereafter convert back to list of dicts. If `data_list` is the input list of dicts:

```
tuple_list=list(set([tuple((k,v) for k,v in obs.items()) for obs in data_list]))

dict_list=[{t[0]:t[1] for t in obs} for obs in tuple_list]
```