# how to remove an entire dictionary element if one of its value is repeated in python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have several lists of dicts showing a word and it's position in a sentence (start/end character). However, some words are repeated, but their position in the sentence varies, so I can't find a way to find the duplicates. How can I remove those words from my list of dictionaries?

```
[{'word': 'sun',
 'start': 10,
 'end': 14},
{'word': 'earth',
 'start': 20,
 'end': 26},
{'word': 'sun',
 'start': 30,
 'end': 34}]
```

so I was hoping to get

```
[{'word': 'sun',
 'start': 10,
 'end': 14},
{'word': 'earth',
 'start': 20,
 'end': 26}]
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried/researched?

Comment: sorry, I corrected the code. But I mean, if the word 'sun' appears twice, but with different start/end, how can I find and remove it?

Comment: I updated my comment. [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9427163/1324033)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your list is called `l`. Then you could use:

```py
alreadyUsed = list()
stuffToDelete = list()
for d in l:
    word = d['word']
    if word in alreadyUsed:
        stuffToDelete.append(d)
    else:
        alreadyUsed.append(word)
for d in stuffToDelete:
    del l[l.index(d)]
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I get an error saying: 
`ValueError: '‘pluto' is not in list', and 'pluto' is definitely one of the repeated words :(

Comment: Sorry, I asked the list to search for the actual word, not the dictionary that contains the word. I'll edit my post.