# Find duplicate objects in a dictionary list based on combination of values

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following dictionary list

```
dict_list = [{"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q1"},                    
             {"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q2"},                    
             {"feed_id": 103, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q1"},                    
             {"feed_id": 103, "query_id": 202, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q3"},                    
             {"feed_id": 103, "bind_id": 301, "bname": "b1"},                                     
             {"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "qname":"q1"}]
```

I want to remove duplicates based on the combination of three keys. The result list should look like

```
result_dict_list = [{"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q1"},            
                    {"feed_id": 103, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q1"},            
                    {"feed_id": 103, "query_id": 202, "bind_id": 301, "qname":"q3"},            
                    {"feed_id": 103, "bind_id": 301, "bname": "b1"},                             
                    {"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "qname":"q1"}]
```

These are the requirements in terms of object structure

1. `feed_id` will exist for all objects and cannot be null
2. `query_id` and `bind_id` are optional. If even one of the property does not exist, no need to check whether the object is duplicate
3. All three properties values are numbers. If the key exist, value cannot be null.
4. There can be many other properties in each object but to eliminate duplicates we care only about `feed_id, query_id and bind_id`
5. Order of the list doesn't matter

What would be the most efficient way to remove duplicates from the list in python?

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Is the order of the resulting list important?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)

Comment: I missed a couple of points in the requirements. Made an update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution for now. But wanted to check if there is a better way to do it. This is what I have.

```
list_with_all_keys = []
properties = ['feed_id', 'query_id', 'bind_id']

for obj in dict_list:
    if all(key in obj for key in properties):
        list_with_all_keys.append(obj)

dict_with_no_duplicates = {tuple(d[k] for k in properties): d 
                                      for d in list_with_all_keys}

list_with_missing_keys = [i for i in dict_list if i not in list_with_all_keys]

result_dict = dict_with_no_duplicates.values() + list_with_missing_keys
```

Pyfiddle for reference https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/268c14a1-ccd9-471c-8c61-18ae90d81f47/?i=true

Answer (score 2):

It's fairly straightforward:

```
dict_list = [{"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301},                    
             {"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301},                    
             {"feed_id": 103, "query_id": 201, "bind_id": 301},                    
             {"feed_id": 103, "query_id": 202, "bind_id": 301},                    
             {"feed_id": 103, "bind_id": 301},                                     
             {"feed_id": 101, "query_id": 201}]
result_dict_list = []
for d in dict_list:
    if d not in result_dict_list:
        result_dict_list.append(d)

print(result_dict_list)
```

Comment: I missed a requirement and I have updated the question. Thanks for the reply!