# How to check for duplicates across entire json row?

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a json with 1000s of lines and I won't bore you with that here but this is a quick example of the dataset.

```
{
    "places": [
        {
            "place_name": "123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL",
            "address": "809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A",
            "city": "PEORIA",
            "state": "IL",
            "zip": "61614",
            "geo_location": "40.89564657,-89.60566821",
            "data": {}
        },
        {
            "place_name": "123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL",
            "address": "809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A",
            "city": "PEORIA",
            "state": "IL",
            "zip": "61615",
            "geo_location": "40.78878653,-89.605669034",
            "data": {}
        },
        {
            "place_name": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.",
            "address": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.",
            "city": "LANSING",
            "state": "IL",
            "zip": "60438",
            "geo_location": "41.565952019,-87.556316006",
            "data": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see the first two places are almost identical but they have different zips and geo locations making them not a duplicate. I currently have a script that just looks at the place_name being duplicated but this is returning me places that aren't actually duplicates. Essentially I would like my script to look at each row and if one row is the same as the another row then delete that row.
Here is my code thus far.

```
import collections
import pandas as pd
places = pd.read_json("test.json")
place_names = [item['place_name'] for item in places['places']]
print([item for item, count in collections.Counter(place_names).items() if count > 1])
```

Comment: Does [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python) answer your question?

Comment: @user696969 not necessarily. Those all involve a bunch of tuples and lists and hashing but I was wondering if there is a simpler way.

Comment: That is the way.

Answer (score 2):

As @user696969 pointed out, there are already useful answers in [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python). The accepted answer by @jcollado works quite nicely, BUT you have a dictionary as a value inside the dictionaries, which is the value of the key `data`. So, running that piece of code without doing any changes to your dataset will give you `TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'`. To fix that, you can implement the following check

```
new_d = d.copy()
for k, v in d.items(): 
    if type(v) is dict: # if a value is a dictionary, convert that value to a tuple
        new_d[k] = tuple(v.items())
```

So, the entire code becomes

```
seen = set()
new_l = []
for d in l:
    new_d = d.copy()
    for k, v in d.items():
        if type(v) is dict:
            new_d[k] = tuple(v.items())
            
    t = tuple(new_d.items())
    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)
        new_l.append(d)
```

For example, let `l` be

```
l = [{
        "place_name": "123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL",
        "address": "809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A",
        "city": "PEORIA",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "61614",
        "geo_location": "40.89564657,-89.60566821",
        "data": {}
    },
    {
        "place_name": "123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL",
        "address": "809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A",
        "city": "PEORIA",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "61615",
        "geo_location": "40.78878653,-89.605669034",
        "data": {"hey": 1}
    },
    {
        "place_name": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.",
        "address": "18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.",
        "city": "LANSING",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "60438",
        "geo_location": "41.565952019,-87.556316006",
        "data": {"hey": 2}
    },
    {
        "place_name": "123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL",
        "address": "809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A",
        "city": "PEORIA",
        "state": "IL",
        "zip": "61615",
        "geo_location": "40.78878653,-89.605669034",
        "data": {"hey": 1}
    },
]
```

After I run the code, `new_l` becomes

```
>>> new_l
    [{'place_name': '123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL',
      'address': '809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A',
      'city': 'PEORIA',
      'state': 'IL',
      'zip': '61614',
      'geo_location': '40.89564657,-89.60566821',
      'data': {}},
     {'place_name': '123 YOU N ME PRESCHOOL',
      'address': '809 W DETWEILLER DR STE A',
      'city': 'PEORIA',
      'state': 'IL',
      'zip': '61615',
      'geo_location': '40.78878653,-89.605669034',
      'data': {'hey': 1}},
     {'place_name': '18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.',
      'address': '18144 GLEN TERRACE ST.',
      'city': 'LANSING',
      'state': 'IL',
      'zip': '60438',
      'geo_location': '41.565952019,-87.556316006',
      'data': {'hey': 2}}]
```

The dictionary with `"data": {"hey": 1}` only appears once now. If you know that the value of `"data"` is the only one that can be a dictionary, then remove the `for loop` and do

```
seen = set()
new_l = []
for d in l:
    d["data"] = tuple(d["data"].items())
    t = tuple(d.items())
    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)
        d["data"] = {k: v for k, v in d["data"]} # back to dictionary
        new_l.append(d)
```

That will improve the performance overall.

Comment: This works great but only if you put the json in a variable. But I have 1000s of lines and need to read the json in with pandas or json.load or something with causes a JSON object must be str error.

Comment: ^f = open('test.json')
places = json.loads(f)

Comment: You can't load the JSON file as a dictionary? I mean, you could do `with open('test.json') as f: places = json.load(f)`, which will save the entire JSON content as a dictionary. From there, you can apply this algorithm.

Comment: I get this error when doing that "TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not TextIOWrapper"

Comment: As far as I know, that happens when you use `json.loads()` and not `json.load()`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there are more efficient way though. Usually, to remove duplicates from the list, you can use `list(set(list_variable))` but that only works if `list_variable` only contains hashable values, since dictionary object aren't hashable, you can't use that approach. There are many approaches mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python). One alternative way I can think of is to convert to dictionary object of each `place` into string (`str(place)`) and then use them as key for a dictionary and since dictionary only store unique key string, you will only get unique places in the new dictionary

```
unique_places = list({str(place): place for place in places["places"]}.values())
```

Comment: that doesn't look at every element of the row, and will return duplicates

Comment: @Shultz The `str(place)` will essentially turn the `place` dictionary into a JSON string so every element will be looked at in order to do so. Could you provide a sample data in your test case that caused the duplicates?