# TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' Removing duplicates from compex List structure

Tags: python, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I'm trying to remove duplicates from following structure:

```py
data = [
    {
        'author': 'Isav Tuco',
        'authorId': 62,
        'tags': ['fire', 'works']
    },
    {
        'author': 'Sham Isa',
        'authorId': 23,
        'tags': ['badminton', 'game']
    },
    {
        'author': 'Isav Tuco',
        'authorId': 62,
        'tags': ['fire', 'works']
    }
]
```

I've tried with the below method available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python) .
Code to remove duplicates from list of dictionaries:

```py
seen = set()
new_list = []
for d in data:
    t = tuple(d.items())
    if d not in seen:
        seen.add(d)
        new_list.append(d)
```

Comment: dont see any code you tried. [ask] && [mre] apply here - we can not help you fix your problematic code if you do not share it: [edit] your question.

Comment: @PatrickArtner, I have edited my question with what I tried to remove the duplicates but it fails at 'when a dictionary key has a list as a value.

Comment: I have tried this from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution from [Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python) is not fully appliccable because you have inner lists.

You would need to tuplify them as well for usage in a set.

One way to do it would be:

```
data = [{'author': 'Isav Tuco',
         'authorId': 62,
         'tags': ['fire', 'works']},
        {'author': 'Sham Isa',
         'authorId': 23,
         'tags': ['badminton', 'game']},
        {'author': 'Isav Tuco',
         'authorId': 62,
         'tags': ['fire', 'works']}]

seen = set()
new_list = []
for d in data:
    l = []
    # use sorted items to avoid {"a":1, "b":2} != {"b":2, "a":1} being
    # different when getting the dicts items
    for (a,b) in sorted(d.items()):
        if isinstance(b,list):
            l.append((a,tuple(b))) # convert lists to tuples
        else:
            l.append((a,b))

    # convert list to tuples so you can put it into a set 
    t = tuple(l)

    if t not in seen:
        seen.add(t)          # add the modified value
        new_list.append(d)   # add the original value
print(new_list)
```

Output:

```
[{'author': 'Isav Tuco', 'authorId': 62, 'tags': ['fire', 'works']}, 
 {'author': 'Sham Isa', 'authorId': 23, 'tags': ['badminton', 'game']}]
```

This is hacked though - you may want to get your own better solution.