# Dictionary of dictionaries - Removing duplications in only certain keys/values

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary of dictionaries, a sample is below:

```
my_dictionary = {
    "0": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "UK"},
    "1": {"Name": "Steve", "Age": 19, "Country": "Spain"},
    "2": {"Name": "Dave", "Age": 23, "Country": "UK"},
    "3": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "Hong Kong"},
    "4": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "France"},
}
```

I want to remove duplicates in `my_dictonary` if the value in `"Name"` AND `"Age"` is the same. It does not matter which one is removed (there could be many that are the same, I only want one version to remain though).

So in our example above, the output would be:

```
{'0': {'Name': 'Nick', 'Age': 39, 'Country': 'UK'},
 '1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'},
 '2': {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}}
```

As `Nick, 39` was duplicated despite having a different country.

Is there an easy/efficient way of doing this? I have several million rows.

Comment: Do you need to keep the index keys of the outer dictionary or could the output also be a list of unique dicts? Did you already had a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)? Alternatively, I could imagine using a functional approach. Nevertheless, I do not know about the performance of each approach.

Comment: The index key does not matter, although I do need something there if that makes sense? i.e. it doesn't need to be re-indexed, it could go (1, 2, 8, 9, 11) etc.

Comment: You can do a first go over all values to detect the first occurrences of all (name, age) pairs. During this first iteration you can fill both a set with already encountered pairs and another set with the keys of the first occurrences of all pairs. From the set of keys you can simply build your desired dictionary.

Comment: Thats a great way of doing it, thank you cglacet!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Track seen records, for example:

```
my_dictionary = {
    "0": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "UK"},
    "1": {"Name": "Steve", "Age": 19, "Country": "Spain"},
    "2": {"Name": "Dave", "Age": 23, "Country": "UK"},
    "3": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "Hong Kong"},
    "4": {"Name": "Nick", "Age": 39, "Country": "France"},
}

seen = set()
result = {}
for k, v in my_dictionary.items():
    if (v['Name'], v['Age']) not in seen:
        result[k] = v
        seen.add((v['Name'], v['Age']))

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{
    '0': {'Name': 'Nick', 'Age': 39, 'Country': 'UK'}, 
    '1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'}, 
    '2': {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}
}
```

Edit note: Using `set()` (which uses a hash-table) for tracking leads to the overall complexity of `O(n)` for n rows.

Comment: This is great, thank you funnydman! Thats such a good way of doing it, ty :)

Answer (score 1):

Twice dictionary comprehension, this is easier to write, but it will be slower than using set.

```
>>> {(v['Name'], v['Age']): k for k, v in my_dictionary.items()}
{('Nick', 39): '4', ('Steve', 19): '1', ('Dave', 23): '2'}
>>> {k: my_dictionary[k] for k in _.values()}
{'4': {'Name': 'Nick', 'Age': 39, 'Country': 'France'},
 '1': {'Name': 'Steve', 'Age': 19, 'Country': 'Spain'},
 '2': {'Name': 'Dave', 'Age': 23, 'Country': 'UK'}}
```

Comment: Great! Thank you Mechanic Pig! :)

Comment: If you reverse the first iteration order it will get the desired output.

Comment: @cglacet OP doesn't care which one to delete, but this is still a good suggestion :)