# Filtering List of Dictionaries by Value Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries like so:

```
data = [{title:'XYZ',url:'www.xyz.com'},{title:'ABC',url:'www.abc.com'},{title:'XYZ',url:'www.def.com'}]
```

I would like to filter this so that only the non-duplicate titles are retained i.e.:

```
filtered = [{title:'XYZ',url:'www.xyz.com'},{title:'ABC',url:'www.abc.com'}]
```

It doesn't matter which duplicate dictionary is retained. I tried

```
[x for x in data if x['title'] not in data]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hope this works

```
data =[{'title':'XYZ','url':'www.xyz.com'},{'title':'ABC','url':'www.abc.com'},{'title':'XYZ','url':'www.def.com'}]
tested_title=[]
filtered=[]
for test in data:
   test_title=test["title"]
   if test_title not in tested_title:
       tested_title.append(test_title)
       filtered.append(test)
print(filtered)
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are not concerned about which records to keep, following will keep the last records for the duplicates while keeping the non-duplicates:

```py
[x for i, x in enumerate(data)
 if x['title'] not in [item['title'] for item in data[i + 1:]]]

# output:
[{'title': 'ABC', 'url': 'www.abc.com'}, {'title': 'XYZ', 'url': 'www.def.com'}]
```

The idea is to iterate the list using `enumerate` then to check if the title exists in list after index `i`, if not, it'll keep the item else it will skip the item.

Answer (score 0):

```
data = [{'title':'XYZ','url':'www.xyz.com'},{'title':'ABC','url':'www.abc.com'},    {'title':'XYZ','url':'www.def.com'}]
titles = []
i = 0

while len(data)>i:
    d = data[i]
    title = d['title']
    if title in titles:
        data.pop(i)
    else:
        titles.append(title)
        i+=1

    
print(data)
```