# Remove duplicates in an object in JSONiq

Tags: python, json, database, jsoniq

This is an example object that I got:

`{ "query1" : [ { "name" : "John", "id" : 1234 }, { "name" : "Rose", "id" : 3214 }, { "name" : "John", "id" : 1234 } ] }`

How can I remove the duplicates using group by and array navigation / unboxing?

I tried implementing the group by clause after the where clause but did not get the correct answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In JSONiq, you can indeed remove duplicates with a group by and array unboxing, like so:

```
let $data := {
  "query1" : [
    { "name" : "John", "id" : 1234 },
    { "name" : "Rose", "id" : 3214 },
    { "name" : "John", "id" : 1234 }
  ]
}
return {
 "query1" : [
    for $obj in $data.query1[]
    group by $n := $obj.name, $i := $obj.id
    return $obj[1]
  ]
}
```

There is also a generic approach that will work even with unknown fields and more nested values:

```
let $data := {
  "query1" : [
    { "name" : "John", "id" : 1234 },
    { "name" : "Rose", "id" : 3214 },
    { "name" : "John", "id" : 1234 }
  ]
}
return {
  "query1" : [
    for $obj at $i in $data.query1[]
    where
      every $other in $data.query1[][position() lt $i]
      satisfies not deep-equal($obj, $other)
    return $obj
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For remove duplicates item from Json object you can use this code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

data = {
    "query1": [
        {"name": "John", "id": 1234},
        {"name": "Rose", "id": 3214},
        {"name": "John", "id": 1234},
    ]
}

unique_data = {}
for key, array in data.items():
    unique_objects = OrderedDict()
    for obj in array:
        unique_objects[(obj["name"], obj["id"])] = obj
    unique_data[key] = list(unique_objects.values())

print(unique_data)
```

**Result:**

```
{'query1': [{'name': 'John', 'id': 1234}, {'name': 'Rose', 'id': 3214}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to do this way, found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python):

```
data = {
    "query1": [
        {"name": "John", "id": 1234},
        {"name": "Rose", "id": 3214},
        {"name": "John", "id": 1234},
    ]
}

query1 = data.get('query1')

[dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in query1}]
```