# How to remove duplicates from a list of dictionary from a key

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of dictionarys which i want to remove duplicates but only if 1 key value is same.

```
List = [
    {Name:"a", age:2},
    {Name:"b", age:7},
    {Name:"a", age:23},
    {Name:"c", age:16},
]
```

This is my list of dictionarys and i want to sort it and remove duplicates like if i want to do it by name the output should be :

```
List=[
    {Name:"a", age:2},
    {Name:"b", age:7},
    {Name:"c", age:16}
]
```

So how can i do it like this. It took the first Name:a because it was unique but when the second Name:a came it counts it as a duplicate and removes it. How can i do this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python here is the answer, Question should be close

Comment: I think he wants to delete duplicates with a specific key, not the whole dict

Comment: Yes that is the one i was confused i couldn't find it thanks Tanveer