# python how to find duplicated values of yaml file for specific key

Tags: python, yaml

I have a yaml file like this:

```yaml
-
    ip: 1.1.1.1
    status: Active
    type: 'typeA'
-
    ip: 1.1.1.1
    status: Disabled
    type: 'typeA'
-
    ip: 2.2.2.2
    status: Active
    type: 'typeC'
-
    ip: 3.3.3.3
    status: Active
    type: 'typeB'
-
    ip: 3.3.3.3
    status: Active
    type: 'typeC'
-
    ip: 2.2.2.2
    status: Active
    type: 'typeC'
-
```

I'm going to find any duplicate IPs which `type` is the same.

For example, IP `1.1.1.1` has two entries and both types are `typeA`, so it should be considered. But IP `3.3.3.3`'s type is not the same so it should not be.

Expected output:

```
IP 1.1.1.1, typeA duplicate
IP 2.2.2.2, typeC duplicate
```

Comment: You don't indicate why there is a comma after the IP address in the first line of the output, but not on the second line. Is that determined by the value for key `type`?

Comment: @Anthon you mean in the `expected output`? That's a typo, sir. Since that's the output, it doesn't much matter. But I really appreciate that. I edit the question and add the comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install `pyyaml` using `pip install pyyaml` then run the python script by replacing `myyaml.yaml` with your `YAML` file

```
import yaml

with open('myyaml.yaml', 'r') as file:
    data = yaml.safe_load(file)

ip_type_map = {}

for entry in data:
    if entry and 'ip' in entry and 'type' in entry:
        ip, entry_type = entry['ip'], entry['type']
        print(f"IP {ip}, {entry_type} duplicate") if (ip in ip_type_map and entry_type == ip_type_map[ip]) else ip_type_map.update({ip: entry_type})
    else:
        print("Invalid entry in YAML data.")
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways you can do this. All of them require you loading yaml in with a parser. Use a library like pyyaml https://pypi.org/project/PyYAML/

```py
import yaml

with open('yaml_file.yml', 'r') as stream:
    file = yaml.safe_load(stream)
```

First way, loop over each row making note of the types you've seen, storing them in a list, along with the indexes of duplicates. This will preserve the original list order.

```py
rows_to_remove = []
rows_seen = []
for idx, row in enumerate(file):
   if (row['ip'], row['type']) in rows_seen:
      rows_to_remove.append(idx)
      continue
   rows_seen.append((row['ip'], row['type']))

for row_idx in rows_to_remove:
   file.pop(row_idx)
```

Create a new list using a list comprehension.

```py
[dict(t) for t in {tuple(d.items()) for d in file}]
```

This loops over each line in the list, turning the dictionary into a tuple and storing that in a set, which doesn't allow for duplicates. Each unique line is then turned back into a dictionary stored inside of a list.

I'll point out that these questions have already been answered and could be found with some searching.

[How can I parse a YAML file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773805/how-can-i-parse-a-yaml-file-in-python)

[Remove duplicate dict in list in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python)